# When adding an async delegate to an event, how to make the process continue after the event is done? (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm not sure if the title is clear. I mean that if I have code like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public event EventHandler? Started;
    public event EventHandler? Finished;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        Started?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Finished?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        //When adding an async delegate to an event, how to make it run synchronously?
        test.Started += async delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The started event began.");
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            // this string will not be printed
            Console.WriteLine("The started event ended.");
        };
        test.Finished += (_, _) => { Console.WriteLine("Run finished event"); };
        test.DoWork();
    }
}
```

The `Finished` event will be raised before the `Started` runs finished.

Is there's any way to make the `Started` event be raised after `Finished` event is done?

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You can use a WaitHandle : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make the delegate async and stop using EventHandler. Also `DoWork` needs to be async.

```
public class Test
{
    public event Func<object, Task>? Started;
    public event Func<object, Task>? Finished;

    public async Task DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        if (Started is not null)
        {
            await Started.Invoke();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End");
        if (Finished is not null)
        {
            await Finished.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        //When adding an async delegate to an event, how to make it run synchronously?
        test.Started += async delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The started event began.");
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            // this string will not be printed
            Console.WriteLine("The started event ended.");
        };
        test.Finished += (_) => { Console.WriteLine("Run finished event"); return Task.CompletedTask; };
        await test.DoWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need to use args from the EventHander, so Func may not the answer for me :(

Comment: Use a Func with arguments then. I updated it to pass one argument. The key point is that if you want to await the callback then it needs to return a task or something awaitable.

Comment: It seems great! But it's evening at my place, I'll try it tomorrow. And I'll accept this if it works for my project :)